# Помощь в изучении кода C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xna

Изучаю процесс создания игры Flappy Bird в Visual Studio 2013 (XNA).
Процесс создания доступен на [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrfPk7qRmVs).

Конкретно, я не совсем точно понимаю, что автор описывает в InputManagers.cs
Привожу пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace FlappyBird.Managers
{
    public class InputManager
    {

        private KeyboardState _oldKS;
        private KeyboardState _KS;

        public InputManager()
        {
            Statics.INPUT = this;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            if (_KS != null)
                _oldKS = _KS;
            _KS = Keyboard.GetState();
        }

        public bool isKeyPressed(Keys k)
        {
            return (_oldKS.IsKeyUp(k) && _KS.IsKeyDown(k));
        }

        public bool isKeyRelease(Keys k)
        {
            return (_oldKS.IsKeyUp(k) && _KS.IsKeyDown(k));
        }

        public KeyboardState currentState()
        {
            return this._KS;
        }
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что этот код имеет к какое то отношение к клавиатуре. Но что именно он делает, я не могу понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, ничего сложного нет.

Центр класса — функция `Update`, в которой класс сохраняет текущее и предыдущее состояния клавиатуры (предыдущее = состояние при предыдущем вызове функции `Update`).

На этом основываются функции `isKeyPressed` и `isKeyRelease` (должно быть, понятно, `Released`), которые сравнивают нажатые клавиши в предыдущем и текущем состоянии, и возвращают флаг, если было изменение. Они крешатся, если до их вызова не был вызван `Update` как минимум дважды.

Класс написан не очень хорошо ещё и по другой причине. Он *несамостоятелен*, так как требует своевременного вызова функции `Update` внешним кодом для своей нормальной работы. Правильнее было бы самому взять на себя ответственность, и не зависеть от внешних факторов.

Ну и имплементация синглтона оставляет желать лучшего. Правильно делать синглтон так, как описано [здесь](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Это вспомогательный класс, который используют, чтобы определять была нажата клавиша на клавиатуре или нет. Почитайте внимательно код в остальных исходниках чтобы посмотреть, как работает isKeyPressed.
P.S.
isKeyPressed и isKeyRelease содержит один и тот же код. Либо вы опечатались, либо качество кода туториала оставляет лучшего. На самом деле я не хочу сказать, что не стоит использовать этот туториал. Судя по ютубу, игра в туториале в итоге написана и это уже заслуживает интереса. Пройдите за автором до конца, если что-то не понятно в коде - вернитесь к этому позже. +1 к программированию вы определенно получите.

Comment: Ссылка на файл с данным кодом <https://github.com/Nakato53/FlappyBirdCloneXNAChallenge/blob/master/FlappyBird/FlappyBird/FlappyBird/Managers/InputManager.cs>.
Ссылка на сам проект <https://github.com/Nakato53/FlappyBirdCloneXNAChallenge/tree/master/FlappyBird/FlappyBird>